# Replacing your paths, with universal paths - Linux

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, path, filepath

I have created a small Node.js application, which also invokes a python script.

In both the node server and the python script, exist hardcoded paths.

In Python's case:

```
myStoreDir = '/home/user1/Desktop/app/dataContainer/'
```

In Node's case:

```
var pathAndFileName = '/home/user1/Desktop/app/dataContainer/'+fileName;
```

Of course the small app works flawlessly in my system. But when i gave the code to a colleague to run the app in a docker container, he had problems obvisouly, as these paths did not exist on his system.

Is there a way to declare those paths differently, both in node.js, and in python.
So that anyone can run it?

Please have in mind, that the file structure `/app/dataContainer`, will exist for sure, because this is the result of a `git pull`.

Is there a way to fix this, so the path previous to `/app`, is fixed to the location of the git pulled directory?

Comment: Relative paths. The OS will look up things relative to the current working directory; start the script in the `app/dataContainer` directory and you can remove the hard-coded paths entirely.

Comment: I am running the node.js server at the /.../app/ directory. The python script that is invoked by node.js, is located inside /.../app/dataContainer. I have to modify the routes.js, and the python script. What exactly has to be changed?

Comment: Where you have `/long/complex/path/to/app/dataContainer/` replace with `dataContainer/`

Comment: Thanks! The same approach is both for python and node.js's javascript files?

Comment: Relative paths are an OS facility so yes, anything which uses paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use relative paths or provide the path as an environment variable or as part of the arguments when you invoke the scripts

Comment: Can't the code inside python/javascript have a parameter that specifies the current directory of the script?

Comment: That's exactly what the part after "or" describes.

Comment: If you want the current directory of a python file you can use 
the os module and '__file__'.